# Looking for examples of an uncountable proper subgroup of $(\mathbb R,+)$ without using the concept of Hamel basis of $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$

Tags: group-theory, real-numbers

Please give some examples of an uncountable proper subgroup of $(\mathbb R,+)$ that does not depend on Hamel basis of $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$ . Using Hamel basis this is easy as we can find an injective endomorphism $f$ on $(\mathbb R,+)$ which is not a surjection , so $f(\mathbb R) (\ne \mathbb R)$ which has the same cardinaltiy as $\mathbb R$ , is a subgroup  of $(\mathbb R,+)$ , but I don't want to use the concept of Hamel basis , Please help

Comment: @ Pierre-Guy Plamondon : yes , indeed , I edited

Comment: [The answer in MO](http://mathoverflow.net/a/34436/48041) gives an example.

Comment: Can we use a transcendence basis instead? :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila : Yes , if nothing less trivial can be found :-)

Comment: Well, if you assume $2^{\aleph_0}>\aleph_1$, then you can easily find uncountable subgroups of size $\aleph_1$ (just pick any $\aleph_1$ real numbers and look at the subgroup they generate, for example). But the link given by tetori and [this MathOverflow link](http://mathoverflow.net/q/23202/7206) is really where it's at.

Comment: @AsafKaragila : what I don't understand is how the example in tetori's link is uncountable ?

Comment: It is $G$ which has continuum many points in $[0,1]$. How is not uncountable? :-)

Comment: Maybe $\{0\} \cup$ the set of uncomputable numbers? But the sum of two uncomputable is uncomputable?

Comment: @EmilioNovati let $x$ be an uncomputable number. Then $1 - x$ is also uncomputable, and $x + (1 - x) = 1$. So, uncomputable numbers with zero do not form a subgroup.

Answer (score 1):

•  In [1], Erdös & Volkmann provide examples of additive subgroups $G$ of $\mathbb R$ for each Hausdorff dimension $s$ with $0 \le s \le 1$.  These are $F_\sigma$-sets. They have cardinal $2^{\aleph_0}$. Elements of the sets are those with certain "factorial base" expansions.

•  A generalized construction is given in [2], Example 12.2:

> Fix $0 < s < 1$.  Let $n_0, n_1, n_2,\dots$be a rapidly increasing sequence of integers, say with $n_{k+1} \ge \max\{n_k^k,4 n_k^{1/s}\}$ for each $k$.  For $r=1,2,3,\dots$ let
>   $$
> F_r = \{x \in \mathbb R\;:\; |x-p/n_k| \le r n_k^{-1/s} \text{ for some integer
> $p$, for all $k$}\}
> $$
>   and let $F = \bigcup_{r=1}^\infty F_r$.  Then $\mathrm{dim}_{\mathrm{H}} F = s$,
>   and $F$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb R$ under addition.

• In [3] Chris Miller and I showed that a proper Borel  *subring* of $\mathbb R$ can only have Hausdorff dimension $0$.  But it may still be uncountable.  If $C \subseteq \mathbb R$ is a Cantor set such that all Cartesian powers $C^k$ have Hausdorff dimension $0$, then the ring $\mathbb Z[C]$ generated by it is uncountable and has Hausdorff dimension $0$.

[1] P. Erdös & B. Volkmann, "Additive Gruppen mit vorgegebener Hausdorffscher Dimension", *J. Reine Angew. Math.* **221** (1966) 203--208

[2] K. Falconer, *Fractal Geometry: Mathematical Foundations and Applications*, Wiley, 2003

[3] G. Edgar & C. Miller, "Borel subrings of the reals", *Proc. Amer. Math. Soc.*
**131** (2002) 1121--1129